# Report in SSRS and Send Mail After Converting into PDF

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, reporting-services

I need your help 
Please any one can help me...
I need to generate report through Procedure in SSRS after this convert in to PDF and send mail.
I need any example through SQL server 
I also work on Visual studio and create report and convert into PDF and also send mail 
but Now I need all work in SQL server.

Answer (score 2):

I think that your question is very vague, I only comment you that everything that you are requesting is perfectly managed by SSRS, you should build your report first, once time that you have completed, the next step is going to SSRS Portal y configure Subscription inside of the report, here you could choose the Render Format and assign the emails that you want your report would be sent.